# W2UI - Making a record editable = false doesn't work

Tags: w2ui

I'm trying to make some records editable and others not. Even the demo isn't working.

http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#/grid/21

Will appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The demo you've linked uses the old w2ui 1.4 notation, where w2ui specific properties where "directly" part of the record object.

Since w2ui 1.5rc1 you will have to encapsulate w2ui specific properties inside a w2ui object.

That means that `record.editable` must be written as `record.w2ui.editable`.

Example old notation:

```
record = {
    recid      : null,   // unique record id
    [field-1]  : '',     // field 1
    [field-2]  : '',     // field 2
    ...
    [field-N]  : '',     // field N
    style      : '',     // additional CSS style for <tr ...> tag  or for <td ...> tag if it is an object
    summary    : false,  // indicates if it is a summary record (summary records appear on the bottom)
    editable   : true,   // indicate is record is editable (must have column.ediable property set)
    expanded   : 'none', // can be true | false | 'none' | 'spinner'
    changes    : undefined  // readonly, object with user changes by inline editing
}
```

Example new notation:

```
record = {
    recid      : null,   // unique record id
    [field-1]  : '',     // field 1
    [field-2]  : '',     // field 2
    ...
    [field-N]  : '',     // field N
    w2ui       : {
        style        : '',     // additional CSS style for <tr ...> tag  or for <td ...> tag if it is an object
        class        : '',     // additional CSS class for <tr ...> tag  or for <td ...> tag if it is an object
        summary      : false,  // indicates if it is a summary record (summary records appear on the bottom)
        editable     : true,   // indicate is record is editable (must have column.editable property set)
        expanded     : 'none', // can be true | false | 'none' | 'spinner'
        changes      : null,   // readonly, object with user changes by inline editing
        colspan      : null,   // colspan object, e.g. { field: 5, ...}
        hideCheckBox : false,  // hide checkbox for this record if grid.show.selectColumn is set
        children     : [],     // array of record objects, can have sub children
        parent_recid : null,   // (internally set, id of the parent record, when children are copied to records array)
    }
}
```

For the demo that means that the record

```
{ recid: 9, int: 1000, money: 3400, percent: 100, date: '2/1/2014',
                style: 'background-color: #ffcccc', editable: false }
```

must be changed to

```
{ recid: 9, int: 1000, money: 3400, percent: 100, date: '2/1/2014', w2ui: {
                style: 'background-color: #ffcccc', editable: false } }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9qd3sobg/

Comment: Mike, Thanks for that info. It's much appreciated!  Bill

Comment: @Bill you're welcome. Please consider to mark the answer as accepted and optionally upvote.